# Load image from sever inside image slider using swiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to load image from server in a slide show with `SwiftUi` but image is not loading in the slide show. please see my code below

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ImageCarouselView<Content: View>: View {
    private var numberOfImages: Int
    private var content: Content
    
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    init(numberOfImages: Int, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.numberOfImages = numberOfImages
        self.content = content()
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            // 1
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    self.content
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .leading)
                .offset(x: CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * -geometry.size.width, y: 0)
                .animation(.spring())
                .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                    self.currentIndex = (self.currentIndex + 1) % (self.numberOfImages == 0 ? 1 : self.numberOfImages)
                }
                
                // 2
                HStack(spacing: 3) {
                    // 3
                    ForEach(0..<self.numberOfImages, id: \.self) { index in
                        // 4
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: index == self.currentIndex ? 10 : 8,
                                   height: index == self.currentIndex ? 10 : 8)
                            .foregroundColor(index == self.currentIndex ? Color.blue : .white)
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                            .animation(.spring())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my view

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
    
    @State var index = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            //MainView(with:"https://govcard.net/banners/banner1.jpg")
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ImageCarouselView(numberOfImages: 3) {
                                     
                    Image("image_carousel_1")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .clipped()
                    Image("image_carousel_2")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .clipped()
                    Image("image_carousel_3")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .clipped()
                }
                
            }.frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
}
```

i want to use url instead of asset image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've seen the easiest way would be to add the [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) `Swift package` to your project.`import KingfisherSwiftUI` to your swift file and use the `KFImage(myUrl)`.

```
import KingfisherSwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    //...
    KFImage(URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")!)
}
```

Here are the steps to add the `Kingfisher` to your project:

1. Select File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency.
2. Enter https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git in the "Choose Package Repository" dialog.
3. In the next page, specify the version resolving rule as "Up to Next Major" with "5.14.0" as its earliest version.